# Best way to expand_dim and repeat a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array that is of shape (1,5).

```py
arr = np.arange(5)
arr = np.expand_dims(arr, axis=0)
```

I want to make an array that is of shape (1,4,5) with each value divided by 4. Is there another way to do this besides from the below solution?

```py
arr2 = np.expand_dims(arr, axis=1)
arr2 = np.repeat(arr2, 4, axis=1)
arr2 = arr2*0.25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [np.broadcast_to](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html)

```
arr2 = np.broadcast_to(arr, shape=(1, 4, 5))
arr2 = arr2 * 0.25
```

or as suggested in the comments

```
arr2 = np.broadcast_to(arr * 0.25, shape=(1, 4, 5))
```

Comment: Or directly, `arr2 = np.broadcast_to(arr*0.25, shape=(1, 4, 5))` ;)